# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting to Highlight Minimum Value but Ignoring Blank Cells

Tags: google-sheets, rounding, min, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a conditional formatting rule to highlight cells within a specific range with the lowest minimum value BUT using the rounded value (to two decimal places), NOT the true value.

Example:

| Header A | Header B |
| --- | --- |
| $7.499 | $7.5 |
| $8 | $7.5001 |
| $7.555 | $9 |

I've tried these conditional formatting rules...

```
=ROUND(A2:B=MIN($A$2:$B),2)
```

^This only returns A2 ($7.499) as TRUE but should return A2, B2, and B3 as TRUE.

```
=A2:B=ROUND(MIN($A$2:$B),2)
```

^This only returns values of $0 (zero) as TRUE. Maybe because it needs to ignore blank cells?

```
=A2:B=ROUND(MIN(FILTER($A$2:$B,$A$2:$B>0)),2)
=A2:B=ROUND(MIN(FILTER($A$2:$B,$A$2:$B<>0)),2)
```

^So I tried both of these variations with a filter in an attempt to ignore blank cells, but then it doesn't work at all.

These columns are formatted as currency but the true value behind what is "displayed" are the values I've shown in the example table.

If anyone could help, I would be very appreciative. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You also need to rounding before calculate minimum value. Try-

```
=INDEX(ROUND(A2:B4,2)=MIN(ROUND(A2:B4,2)))
```

[image]

> > In conditional formatting rule-

```
=INDEX(ROUND(A2,2)=MIN(ROUND($A$2:$B$4,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it works but only if there are no blank entries. Unfortunately, I need to to work while ignoring blank cells. Is there an easy-ish workaround for that? Thanks again!

Comment: @ComputerCandy Can you share a sample google-sheet for better clarification.

Comment: Thank you! Here is a test sheet where E2:F is the range for the conditional formatting. (Green cell with blue text.) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cv9K40OeI6aPllJ3EhMCiVl1AAadpFyGlKmnvhFxs0Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the test sheet, $2.50 is the lowest value in the range E2:F. E18=2.49916666666667, E19=2.49916666666667, and F18=2.49833333333333 but all three should be highlighted as MIN values if everything was working as desired. Thanks again!

Comment: I messed with it a bit more and what it seems to be doing is treating blank cells as zeros. If it could ignore blanks but not literal zeros, that would be ideal. Thanks again!

Comment: I played with it a lot and finally came up with something that worked. Here is what I wound up with... =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E2)), ROUND(E2, 2) = MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK($E$2:$F)), ROUND($E$2:$F, 2), ))))

Answer (score 1):

I came close many times but kept running into the obstacle of it treating blank cells as zeros. I could have had it ignore zeros but I didn't want it to ignore actual literal zeros. Instead, here is what I finally came up with in the end:

```
= AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)), ROUND(A2, 2) = MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK($A$2:$B)), ROUND($A$2:$B, 2), ))))
```